# ANOVA Test Necessity

Tags: correlation, anova, post-hoc

I have a question which may seem very simple to someone with more experience in statistics.

I have performed a two-factor ANOVA test, without replication, in order to test if there is a significant difference between the means of 4 groups. What is the purpose of doing an ANOVA test when Post-HOC T-tests can be done between each group? What added implication does an ANOVA test have over individual Post-HOC tests?

I am also trying to find a correlation between these means and an independent variable. Once I have done an ANOVA test which shows that there is a significant difference between these means, is it absolutely mandatory to do additional Post-HOC tests when justifying my conclusion?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANOVA is joint test for equality of all means, whereas, post-hoc is performed between only two groups. Pair-wise comparison also make sense, **but it reduces the power of the test**. That is why, ANOVA is performed first (which has high power as compared to doing test for two groups). If null hypothesis is rejected, then only post-hoc test is performed.

For your second part, if you are interested to know, where the differences exist, then you should go for post-hoc analysis.